# Is it incorrect to use delete out of scope like this?

Tags: c++, new-operator

```
int* func()
{
   int* i=new int[3];
   return i; 
}

void funcc()
{
   int* tmp=func();
   //delete allocated memory after use
   delete[] tmp;
}
```

My opinion is that the compiler, when compiling funcc has no way to know that there is 3 int to be deleted, for example if func is in another file.

Comment: I would think that `delete` would most often be used "out of scope" in the sense that you don't release the pointer in the same scope you allocate it. Ownership of the pointer is determined by the developer of the application. The point at which it should be released may not be the point in which it was allocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the [C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/num-elems-in-new-array.html):

> **[16.14] After p = new Fred[n], how does the compiler know there are n
>   objects to be destructed during delete[] p?**
>
> Short answer: Magic.
>
> Long answer: The run-time system stores the number of objects, n,
>   somewhere where it can be retrieved if you only know the pointer, p.
>   There are two popular techniques that do this. Both these techniques
>   are in use by commercial-grade compilers, both have tradeoffs, and
>   neither is perfect. These techniques are:
>
> - Over-allocate the array and put n just to the left of the first Fred object.
> - Use an associative array with p as the key and n as the value.

Answer (score 6):

That's the way `delete` is intended to be used, and it's fine. The array size is stored somewhere behind the scenes, so that `delete[]` will do the right thing wherever it happens.

However, juggling pointers like this is error prone: it's easy to lose the pointer before deleting the array, or for the logic to get so complicated that you end up deleting the same array twice. You'd be better off using a class to manage the array for you:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> func() {
    return std::vector<int>(3);
}

void funcc() {
    auto tmp = func();
    // no need to do anything - the vector frees its memory automatically
}
```

Comment: Or consider using boost::scoped_array or boost::shared_array which manage the lifetime of the array for you.

Comment: @DaleWilson: `scoped_array`, being scope-bound, can't be returned from a function. `shared_array` (or its standard equivalent) is useful if you want shared ownership, but overly complicated if you don't.

Comment: The `auto` here is a nice bit of obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze: C++11 is 2 years old now, and the `auto` style of type inference is common to many other languages. Not really obfuscation at this point.

Comment: @ZanLynx C++ (11 or not) is a statically typed language; it's not Python.  It's designed to be used on large projects (unlike Python), where many people have to read and understand the code at a later date.  There are a few special cases where `auto` is valid; where the initializer makes the type so obvious it doesn't matter that it isn't spelled out, but this is clearly not one of them.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Difference of opinion. My C++ code from before C++11 would have a typedef here (func_type_t?) which may not be that much more informative than auto. But the code is so much easier to work with when I decide to switch between vector, array or deque.

Comment: @JamesKanze: And I'd love to see you type out `std::vector< std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, int> > >` every time you needed it, instead of using a typedef or auto.

Comment: @JamesKanze: To me, it's shorter and more readable than the redundant type name - quite the opposite of obfuscation. I suppose it might be confusing to those who refuse to keep up to date with the language, but I can't be bothered to complicate my answers by sticking to historic idioms for their benefit.

Comment: @ZanLynx You mean so much easier to break.  Things like the validity of an iterator change when you change the type.  There's a reason why languages with duck typing aren't used on large projects.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It has nothing to do with the history of the language.  `auto` _is_ useful in specific cases.  But using it systematically, like this, is an anti-pattern, which makes program maintenance more difficult.  Someone modifying the code has to know the exact type in order to modify it safely.  Changing the type could break the code, and should require an explicit modification of that code (and not some unrelated code).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Inferring that I'm suggesting you use it "systematically" from a single example is almost as bizarre as comparing implicit static typing to Python's dynamic typing. In my view, it's sensible to use it whenever you don't care about the exact type (which can easily be looked up if you want to know it); if you do care, then in my view that's a smell: the code may be too tightly coupled to whatever is producing the object. Stating the type explicitly can still cause problems (e.g. unexpected implicit conversions) if it changes, so doesn't make the code particularly less fragile.